# Google maps javascript API in GAE app

Tags: api, google-maps, google-app-engine, geocoding

I have a GAE app in which I would like to implement geocoding. I'm trying to do so with the google maps javascript api, but I'm having trouble loading it into my application. I keep getting the following error:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin localhost:8081 is therefore not allowed access."

I already found a couple of similar issues online, but none of the proposed solutions have worked for me so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Some example code would help greatly. The Maps API should support CORS by returning an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header.

Answer (score 0):

It will be great if you can list the trouble shooting steps you took. One fix will be to use the provided [client Lib](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) rather using Ajax

Comment: Hi, the library is actually what I'm trying to use. I load it with a simple script tag like it's shown on your link, but that's what is producing the error. Other than that I tried loading different versions, I tried loading with an API key. This only happens on GAE projects though (either locally or deployed). I can normally use the library otherwise.